# Java Cryptography AES/GCM/NoPadding without IV

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

I'm implementing a PAKE-protocol as a university project and one step of the protocol involves sending encrypted data from a key created via a hash function (I'm using SHA-256). I want to use AES/GCM but do not have an IV so I'm using HKDF to expand the key into an IV and key with the following implementation:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA256Digest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.HKDFBytesGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.HKDFParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class AesGcmSymmetricCipher {

    public static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";

    public static final int GCM_TAG_BITS = 128;
    public static final int IV_BYTES = 12;
    public static final int KEY_BYTES = 32; // AES-256

    private final Cipher cipher;

    public AesGcmSymmetricCipher() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] clearData) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        var spec = expandKeys(key);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, spec.getKeySpec(), spec.getParameterSpec());

        return cipher.doFinal(clearData);
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] key, byte[] cipherData) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        var spec = expandKeys(key);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, spec.getKeySpec(), spec.getParameterSpec());

        return cipher.doFinal(cipherData);
    }

    public String getAlgorithm() {
        return "AES-256/GCM/NoPadding using HKDF";
    }

    private KeyedMaterial expandKeys(byte[] initialKey) {
        var iv = new byte[IV_BYTES];
        var key = new byte[KEY_BYTES];

        var digest = new SHA256Digest();
        var kdf = new HKDFBytesGenerator(digest);
        var parameters = new HKDFParameters(initialKey, null, null);

        kdf.init(parameters);
        kdf.generateBytes(iv, 0, IV_BYTES);
        kdf.generateBytes(key, 0, KEY_BYTES);

        var gcmParameters = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_BITS, iv);
        var keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

        Arrays.clear(iv);
        Arrays.clear(key);

        return new KeyedMaterial(gcmParameters, keySpec);
    }

    private static class KeyedMaterial {

        private final GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec;
        private final SecretKeySpec keySpec;

        public KeyedMaterial(GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec, SecretKeySpec keySpec) {
            this.parameterSpec = parameterSpec;
            this.keySpec = keySpec;
        }

        public GCMParameterSpec getParameterSpec() {
            return parameterSpec;
        }

        public SecretKeySpec getKeySpec() {
            return keySpec;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm interested in feedback especially from a security perspective, if relevant the initial key passed to `encrypt`/`decrypt` is ephemeral and will only be used once for encryption and once for decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thank you for using my Bouncy Castle additions:

> Maarten Bodewes  initial implementation of HKDF and NIST SP 800-108 MAC based KDF functions.

### Design review:

You are trying to emulate Java's Cipher class. However, I don't think this is such a good idea if your `encrypt` methods and is so much different. The `Cipher` class in Java is reusable for the same key (and, unfortunately, same IV) and this one is clearly not. I would not try this hard. Better make this class more specific to the use case and *avoid generic wrapper classes*.

In itself, you may wonder if combining the key derivation and cipher is a good idea. You're removing the `update` functionality, for instance. This is less of a problem if this is for a specific use case.

### Code review:

```
public class AesGcmSymmetricCipher {
```

Better made final.

The name doesn't fully capture what the class is about. `Symmetric` is already captured by `Aes`. The key derivation part is missing on the other hand.

```
public static final int KEY_BYTES = 32; // AES-256
```

I generally use `256 / Byte.SIZE` so it is clear where the 32 comes from, that way you don't need the comment.

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] clearData) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
```

`clearData` is generally called `plaintext` or simply `message` within the crypto community.

Other users will probably wonder what happened with the IV or nonce and where to insert it.

```
Arrays.clear(iv);
Arrays.clear(key);
```

Beware that Oracle made a huge mistakes by making the actual **keys** in software impossible to destroy. You can do this and fool yourself. It's great that you thought of this though - you're not in the wrong here.

```
return "AES-256/GCM/NoPadding using HKDF";
```

Nice but it doesn't capture all the little details - how is the IV calculated, for instance - so it doesn't seem to be of much use. You cannot specify it to anybody and they will know how to implement it.

---

Otherwise the class and design seems spot on to me, so well done.

Comment: Just to stay fair: the crypto API is so old that it was probably Sun who made the design mistake, not Oracle.

Comment: I'm aware that the `Array.clear(...)` does not really clear the keys (I use them after the clear) and wondered when `SecreteKeySpec` clears its private data or if I forgot to do this.

Comment: "You're removing the `update` functionality, for instance"
I actually tried to implement it with update and varargs, but then the tag-verification always failed and through some googleing I found that there is apparently something wrong if you don't use `doFinal(data)` in GCM mode.

Comment: @RolandIllig I don't know, the [`Destroyable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Destroyable.html#destroy--) interface is a late addition that was only introduced in version 8 - it's relatively new. Of course, before that it was missing entirely, so there is that.

Comment: @recke96 Yeah, no, it is always multiple `update()` calls followed by a `doFinal`, even for other modes (CBC mode only removed padding within one of the overloaded `doFinal` methods for instance..